# The News app's live tile is stuck, how do I refresh it?

Tags: 8.1, apps

I've been hearing about how Australian people are the world's richest for about 4 weeks now.

The live tile seems to be stuck. I've tried removing and re-adding the tile and restarting my device.

How do I fix this?

[image: WP news app tile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to delete and reinstall the app from the store.

Comment: I've reinstalled the app and so far the results are positive. The live tile has changed. I'll give it a little bit more time to verify and then I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have allowed the app to run in background(as the picture shows few apps are allowed and few are not) ,also the battery saver is off.
[image]